# Toggle Auto Format On Save with Prettier in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

99% of the time I want VSCode to auto format my files on save with Prettier. For that 1% of the time is there a way to toggle this to off in a way that's quicker than going into the settings and then manually switching it on and off?

I've tried looking for any keyboard bindings but the only one I found was `prettier.open-output`

Answer (score 11):

There is command `Save without Formatting` with the keybinding Cmd+K S

ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38695#issuecomment-423422531

Comment: This is the best answer, it's even better than that toggle formatting plugin. Basically we are asking for a plain save like in the old ways.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from Atom where my prettier extension had a toggle in the menu bar at the bottom of the editor to turn formatting-on-save on or off.

To add this to VS Code, I installed this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tombonnike.vscode-status-bar-format-toggle

Once you install it you will see this in the bottom menu bar:
[image: prettier formatting toggle extension turned on]

When the check mark is there, prettier will format on save if you have that enabled in your VS Code settings under Text Editor --> Formatting.

Once you have a file that you don't want prettier to format, for example when reviewing someone else's code, you can turn off auto-formatting which looks like this:
[image: prettier formatting toggle extension turned off]

Comment: Hi deweydell, could you also provide screenshots of how to use and configure this extension, as well as where to find this "formatting toggle" and explaining what clicking it does? It will definitely help improve the answer for others who are considering your solution. Thank you for the contribution!

Comment: Hi Samuel Liew, thank you for the information. I tried to add the screenshots as images but it said I needed at least 10 reputation to do so, so they are just links. Let me know if there is any other way to improve it.

Comment: Thank you! I've updated your great answer and the images should be showing up now